# Ideapad 330 touchpad double tap to open not working (ubuntu 20.4)

Tags: touchpad, lenovo

Since I tried ubuntu 18.04 back in 2019 I have this issue;

I can't get my touchpad to open files or select text by double tapping it. What should I try to solve this issue?

Ps. Touchpad works just fine for everything else: one tap to select, scroll, 2 clicks to open files, folders and select text.

EDIT: I forgot to mention that 3 taps are recognized as 2 taps

Added xinput list screenshot.[image]

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the reply. I'm not sure what you mean, I'm really newbish to Ubuntu and linux to be really honest. A few years ago I installed ubuntu 18.04 bionic beaver and I had this same issue I'm having now with the 20.04 Focal Fossa.

Comment: Thank you! I just updated my question

Comment: This sounds like the time between clicks needs to be reduced in the Mouse/Touchpad settings 

Comment: Sorry that I took so long to reply @matigo! I tried to mess with this setting but all it did was make the touchpad drag whatever I tried to open :( I'll edit my post with the xinput list.
A weird thing is that it seems to work just fine when I first boot my laptop but then it just stops and I have to triple tap it lol